# Overlay layers on different displays from the same coordinate system

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, overlay, display

I have vector layers from digitizing in Google Earth and vector layers from digitizing of a pdf document. All the layers were projected in the same UTM zone 30N system (EPSG code 32630). However, layers obtained from Google Earth do not overlap with layers obtained from document. What can I do to fix the problem with these layers overlapping. I work with QGIS 3.10.

Comment: Please provide additional information. Should the layers actually overlap, or do they show different areas? How did you load the data into QGIS? How did you go about digitizing the PDF? How large is the distance between both layers?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.